# Javascript code getting cached

Tags: javascript

I am trying a  small experiment. Request you guys to please clarify my doubt. I am hitting a random web page and when the web page is not fully loaded, I am trying to invoke the following javascript code to just see if the document object has been created or not.

```
var intervalId = setInterval(function(){
    console.log(typeof document !== 'undefined');
},500);
```

When the above code is run, it goes on printing **false** even when the page has fully **loaded**

Can anyone explain?

Javascript code is getting cached but how would I get a workaround on this type of problem.

Comment: The answer might be in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Comment: Don't think it's because of closure.